# Bash replace ls with for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, ls

I was given a tip to use [file globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in stead of ls in Bash scripts, in my code I followed the instructions and replaced `array=($(ls))` to:

```
function list_files() { for f in *; do [[ -e $f ]] || continue done }
array=($(list_files))
```

However the new function doen't return anything, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `$(function)` is replaced by what the function prints to stdout. Your function doesn't print anything.

Comment: Once you fix that, it doesn't solve your problem. Parsing the output of your `list_files` function has the same problem as parsing the output of `ls`. If a filename contains whitespace, it will be treated as two names when you assign to the array. You need to do everything you want inside the `for` loop. In the example on that page, there's a `...`, which is where you do what you want with each file.

Comment: OK, so the problem above is that the test works, but it doesn't actually do anything. It just sees that the files exist and then quietly moves on. If you put <code>echo $f</code> before the <code>[[ -e $f ]]</code> test it pipes out the detected files. However this does not work the way I need it to work, when the echo statement is passed in the code; The script echoes the files, then populates the array, which echoes out the same files again... When I remove the echo statement the array is not filled and nothing is piped out. Is there a way to pipe the files in the for loop into a variable or

Comment: The proper way to mark a question as answered is to accept one of the answers, not putting "[Solved]" in the title.

Comment: @Dan-SimonMyrland, please read the above comment by chepner. Do not add "solved" to your title.

Comment: If a problem is solved mark the answer that helped you the most with the accepted answer tick/check (click the hollow tick mark next to the answer). If you found the answer yourself add that as an answer and accept it when you can. What you don't do is and "Solved" or anything similar to the title of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write this:

```
array=(*)
```

Leaving aside that your "list_files" doesn't output anything, there are still other problems with your approach.

Unquoted command substitution (in your case "$(list_files)") will still be subject to "word splitting" and "pathname expansion" (see bash(1) "EXPANSION"), which means that if there are spaces in "list_files" output, they will be used to split it into array elements, and if there are pattern characters, they will be used to attempt to match and substitute the current directory file names as separate array elements.

OTOH, if you quote the command substitution with double quotes, then the whole output will be considered a single array element.